# different behavior with componentDidMount than useEffect when using jquery emoji plugin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, emoji

I’m stuck using a jquery emoji plugin on one of my components until I finish with a custom plugin I’m building.

For some reason, when I call the emoji plugin inside of componentDidMount, everything works **except** the ability to utilize a custom button to show the emoji modal. When I use a custom button, the emoji plugin doesn’t attach the event to the button.

What’s crazy is that I can use the same exact code in useEffect, and it attaches the event listener to the custom button just fine.

I verified that the event listener is not attached by looking in the web console at events attached to the element after the page loaded.

You can easily reproduce this problem by placing this component somewhere in an app (and importing jquery with the [emoji-area plugin](https://github.com/diy/jquery-emojiarea)):

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';

  export default function CommentInput(props) {

    useEffect(() => {
      const id = props.blurtId,
            $wysiwyg = $('#' + id).emojiarea({
            button: '#emoji-btn' + id
          });


      $.emojiarea.path = '/js/jquery/emojis/';
      $.emojiarea.icons = {
        ':smile:'     : 'smile.png',
        ':angry:'     : 'angry.png',
        ':flushed:'   : 'flushed.png',
        ':neckbeard:' : 'neckbeard.png',
        ':laughing:'  : 'laughing.png'
      };

   }, []); 

   return (
     <>
        <textarea id={props.blurtId} className='blurt-comment-input' />
        <i id={'emoji-btn' + props.blurtId} className='fa fa-smile emoji-btn' />  
     </>
   )

}
```

Simply change this to a class component, and you’ll see that within componentDidMount, everything works except the custom button. Any idea what could cause this change in behavior??

Here is the react class component version:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class CommentInput extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

componentDidMount() {
    const id = this.props.blurtId,
          $wysiwyg = $('#' + id).emojiarea({
            button: '#emoji-btn' + id
        });


    $.emojiarea.path = '/js/jquery/emojis/';
    $.emojiarea.icons = {
        ':smile:'     : 'smile.png',
        ':angry:'     : 'angry.png',
        ':flushed:'   : 'flushed.png',
        ':neckbeard:' : 'neckbeard.png',
        ':laughing:'  : 'laughing.png'
    };
}; 

render() {
    return (
        <>
            <textarea id={this.props.blurtId} className='blurt-comment-input' />
            <i id={'emoji-btn' + this.props.blurtId} className='fa fa-smile emoji-btn' />  
        </>
      )
    }
}

export default CommentInput;
```

Comment: Since the code you're having trouble with is with a `class` component, we can't really help you if you don't show us that code.

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It's literally the same exact code.. Just changed to a react class component.. And EVERYTHING works in the class except this button. However, I'll add the class component version even though I think it's a bit much.

Comment: It isn't. :-) Remember, you're asking people to take time out of their day to help you. You want to make that as easy as possible. Thanks in advance for adding it, and as a **runnable** example.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for your patience! I added the class component version. Can I do anything to make this more "runnable?" I'm not really sure what I can do for that, other than post something small on gitgub I suppose...

Comment: Yes -- see the "here's how to do one" link above about Stack Snippets. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ahhh, very cool. This will come in handy. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The big difference between [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) and [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) is that `useEffect` is run after **every** render, not just the first one. Since your `render` outputs a **new** element on each render, after the first render the DOM element you attached the emoji thing to doesn't exist anymore, and a new one with the same ID does.

Options:

- Use [`componentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) to handle the subsequent renders. (You'll still need `componentDidMount` for the first one.)
- Use a [callback ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs).

Answer (score 5):

There is a difference between when `componentDidMount` and `useEffect` fires.

From the useEffect docs :

> Unlike componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate, the function passed
>   to useEffect fires **after layout and paint**